# Is there a way to prevent EF from inserting into a SQL Server computed column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I don't want EF to ignore the column on the class when retrieving records from the database as I need to be able to compare the computed column, but I don't want EF to try to insert values into this column as that will throw a SQL Exception because computed columns cannot be modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DatabaseGenerated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
....

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public int ComputedColumn { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

**DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity**

This specifies that the value of the property will be generated by the database on the INSERT statement. This Identity property cannot be updated.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
public int Id { get; set; }
```

**DatabaseGeneratedOption.Compute** 
Specifies that the value of the property will be generated by the underlying database on insert and then, on each subsequent update. 
Useful for LastAccessTime and things like that

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the fluent API in `OnModelCreating` then you can use

```
entity.Property(e => e.ComputedColumn)
      .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

There is also a `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` and `ValueGeneratedOnUpdate` if the value is only computed on insert or update respectively.