# Entity Framework Core 5 tries to insert value for computed column

Tags: azure, entity-framework-5, .net-5, ef-power-tools, azure-sql-managed-instance

Using Entity Framework 5 and EF Core Power Tools (whith the setting to generate ef 5 code enabled) we get something like the following code generated for each computed column:

```
...HasComputedColumnSql("([LastName]+isnull(' '+[FirstName],''))", true);
```

which is perfectly right.

Unfortunately, trying to create a new entity that has computed columns and trying to save we get the following exception from ef core 5:

> The column '...' cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator

When manualy appending the `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate` after the `HasComputedColumnSql` like so:

```
 ...HasComputedColumnSql("([LastName]+isnull(' '+[FirstName],''))", true).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

everything works fine.

According to the docs this should be automatically be called by `HasComputedColumnSql`.

What can be done to overcome this issue ?

We are using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v5.0.5 package and also we are using an Azure Managed Sql Server Instance

Comment: Weird, for me this works like a charm using EF-core 5.0.5 + Sql Server. Both with `stored: true` and `stored: false` (which shouldn't change the behavior, but just checking).

Comment: Yap Gert, I tried also the true/false of stored prop and it didn't change anything

Comment: One thing I didn't mention is that Sql Server is on Azure (Managed Sql Server)

Comment: @GeorgeMavritsakis were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @madhav no, I haven't

Answer (score 0):

The OP already pointed out the solution: in EF core 5, when scaffolding is used, you have to manually add ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate(). This problem has been fixed in EF core 6.

The patch has been mentioned in [earlier answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60530077/1932338).
This answer elaborates on how to remove manual code from generated code.

Let's say the scaffolded file GenDbContext.cs contains:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.ComputedName).HasMaxLength(100).IsUnicode(false)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("([LastName]+isnull(' '+[FirstName],''))", true);
});
```

There are two options: partial class or inheritance.

A) Partial class in GenDbContext.Extension.cs - requires EF core 3.1+

```
public partial class GenDbContext : DbContext
{
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(entity =>
            entity.Property(e => e.ComputedName).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
        );
    }
}
```

B) Subclass in InheritedDbContext.cs.

```
public class InheritedDbContext : GenDbContext
{
    public InheritedDbContext(DbContextOptions<GenDbContext> options) : base(options) {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(entity =>
            entity.Property(e => e.ComputedName).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
        );
    }
}
```

Then in Startup.cs:

```
// The first line is still necessary as it declares DbContextOptions<GenDbContext>.
services.AddDbContext<GenDbContext>(...options...);
services.AddDbContext<InheritedDbContext>(...same options...);
```

There is no need to repeat the rest of the column settings such as HasMaxLength, IsUnicode and HasComputedColumnSql.